# adding a new columing by normalizing existing columns in a table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am new to SQL and I need help in adding normalized score column to table.

My `division_score` table has following schema

```
id      division    sub_division    score
------------------------------------------
id1     account     current asset   0.97
id1     account     debt            0.96
id2     marketing   brand           0.4
id3     marketing   digital         0.3
id4     marketing   consumer        0.2
id4     marketing   TV              0.8
id5     revenue     customer1       1.09
id5     revenue     customer2       10.9
id5     revenue     customer3       5
```

I want to add a new column normalized_score to this table where

```
normalized_score = 0 if division = 'marketing' else
normalized_score is normalized within the group (id, division) by diving score with sum of the total score in the group 
for example - 
for group id5 and revenue -> entry for id5,revenue,customer1 = 1.09/(1.09+10.9+5)
for group id5 and revenue -> entry for id5,revenue,customer2 = 10.9/(1.09+10.9+5)
```

final output will be like

```
id      division    sub_division    score   normalized_score
-----------------------------------------------------------
id1     account     current asset   0.97    0.503
id1     account     debt            0.96    0.497
id2     marketing   brand           0.4     0.000
id3     marketing   digital         0.3     0.000
id4     marketing   consumer        0.2     0.000
id4     marketing   TV              0.8     0.000
id5     revenue     customer1       1.09    0.064
id5     revenue     customer2       10.9    0.642
id5     revenue     customer3       5       0.294
```

Edit with version
it is `PostgreSQL 10.11`

Comment: Is it MySQL or PostgreSQL? If MySQL, which version?

Comment: PostgreSQL 10.11

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you want to add a "calculated" column to a table, your best option is to create a view that adds the data you need. Given that a view is just an SQL query the problem now is to write a query that extracts the data you need.

You have two requirements:

1. an if/then/else, this maps to PostgreSQL `CASE`
2. an aggregate operation on groups of rows, this maps to PostgreSQL window functions.

The query that gives you what you want would be:

```
SELECT id, division, sub_division, score, 
       CASE division WHEN 'marketing' THEN 0 
       ELSE score/sum(score) OVER (PARTITION BY id, division) AS normalized_score
  FROM division_score
```

And the view:

```
CREATE VIEW division_score_with_normalized_score AS
SELECT id, division, sub_division, score, 
       CASE division WHEN 'marketing' THEN 0 
       ELSE score/(sum(score) OVER (PARTITION BY id, division)) AS normalized_score
  FROM division_score
```

Then you can just query from it:

```
SELECT * FROM division_score_with_normalized_score WHERE id = 'id5';
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the query. Please try.

```
select id, division, sub_division, score, 
case when division = 'marketing' then 0 else score/normalized_score as normalized_score 
from (
    select id, division, sub_division, score, sum(score) over (partition by id, division) as normalized_score from table
    ) t;
```